# Excel - Lookup value in multiple columns

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula, lookup

I have a datasheet with multiple columns that I want to search through - ending up with returning the top row value(s) in the found column(s). How to do this?

My idea would be to combine index with match, but I am rather lost for specific ideas...

```
January February March April May June
      1        2     3     4   5    6
      7        8     9    10  11   12
      2        7     1     8   4    5
      9       10    11    12   6    3
```

E.g. Search for: ID 3 - should return: March, June

Regards,

Nyborg

Comment: I would suggest that you have a go at this in VBA, I can't think of a way to do this with just excel formulas. You may need to check out a tutorial which takes you through the basics such as how to loop through a range of cells if you are not already familiar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a VLOOKUP for each columns and after build the result
Following the Scheme:

[image]

```
A7 -> =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$9;A1:A5;1;);"")="";"";A1)          and autocomplete
D9 -> =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCATENATE(A7;",";B7;",";C7;",";D7;",";E7;",";F7);",,";",");",,";",");",,";",")
D10 -> =IF(RIGHT(D9;1)=",";LEFT(D9;LEN(D9)-1);D9)
```

Formula for D9 & D10 it's only to have a good display of the results.

**UPDATE Version:**
Considering you agree to have the Row 7 ... You can simplyfy using the Result formula:

```
=INDEX(List;SMALL(IF(List<>"";COLUMN(List)-MIN(COLUMN(List))+1);1))&IFERROR(", " & INDEX(List;SMALL(IF(List<>"";COLUMN(List)-MIN(COLUMN(List))+1);2));"")&IFERROR(", " & INDEX(List;SMALL(IF(List<>"";COLUMN(List)-MIN(COLUMN(List))+1);3));"")
```

*List* it's the name Range of Row 7. The formula shall be apply with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.
This formula collect the first 3 value.
If you want more, add for each nth value you have:

```
&IFERROR(", " & INDEX(List;SMALL(IF(List<>"";COLUMN(List)-MIN(COLUMN(List))+1);3));"")
```

changing the last numer (in this case 3) and putting 4, 5, 6 ...
Obviusly if the result can be a lot, have few sense... **Consider to use VBA !**

Comment: Nice code. However the data sheet I have runs 50+ columns, and I wanted to avoid VBA by just using "simple advanced" formulas. Therefore I was looking at a method to look/search across multiple (2+) columns and return the equivalent headers.